# Intro to 3d animating with Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, graphics, 3d, blender

I'm not looking to make a game, I only want to make animated 3d videos. I'm a complete beginner with Unity and have completed some tutorial for the very basics, and have some experience 3d modelling in blender.

Any suggestions for a tutorial playlist/videos/blog? A lot of the Youtube tutorials I've found kind of assume you have the basics down (which i don't) and it leaves me lost at times. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Unity is a game enginge, after all so you should probably use a 3D animation program - such as blender - to create (non-interactive) animations. If you already have modelling skills in blender perhaps you should try working with blender animation?

Here are some ressources that might help:

- https://www.blender.org/features/animation/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_C2ClFO3FAY